# C# converting a VBA macro to C# with custom RGB color

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, rgb, office-automation

In converting a VBA macro to a plugin coded in C#, I have run into the following impasse.

The original VBA code is:

```vb
Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
Selection.Font.Size = 14
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.Font.BoldBi = True
Selection.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(173, 216, 230)
```

Converted to C# with the `Office.Interop` namespace:

```cs
using Microsoft.Office;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();
var Selection = oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection;

Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
Selection.Font.Size = 14;
Selection.Shading.Texture = Word.WdTextureIndex.wdTextureNone;
Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic;
Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.ColorFormat.RGB(173, 216, 230);
```

This code won't compile as the `RGB` is not a Method. I am trying to figure out how to do this with using the available methods, but no luck so far.

I would appreciate any advice on this or any description that would explain the conversion.

**Update:**

Actually, it looks like the following works:

```
Color mycolor = Color.FromArgb(173, 216, 230);
Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = (Word.WdColor)(mycolor.R + 0x100 * mycolor.G + 0x10000 * mycolor.B);
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15789429/6201755) uses the same approach. But it still looks too complex...

**Update 2:**

With the suggestions below this seems to be the smoothest approach:

```
Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(172,216,230);

private Word.WdColor RGB(int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
    return (Word.WdColor)p1 + (0x100 * p2) + (0x10000 * p3);
}
```

Comment: You could try the `Color.ToArgb()` method and see if that gives you the same color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RGB` function you're actually calling in your VBA code, is located in the VBA standard library, in the `Information` module - at least according to [Rubberduck 2.0](http://www.rubberduckvba.com)'s context-sensitive status bar (disclaimer: I wrote that feature):

[image: Rubberduck 2.0's context-sensitive status bar]

That `RGB` function really does nothing more than intake 3 numbers and output a corresponding RGB hex value.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13075335/1188513) asks specifically how to convert from `System.Drawing.Color` to a `WdColor` value - and the accepted answer looks pretty much exactly like your "too complex" code. Another solution would be to import `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and use the same `Information.RGB` function... but I cringe whenever I see the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` imported anywhere in a .NET project - it reeks of something being done wrong.

Instead, you could make a simple extension method:

```
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.Interop.Word;

static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static WdColor ToWdColor(this Color color)
    {
        return (WdColor)(color.R + 0x100 * color.G + 0x10000 * color.B);
    }
}
```

Which turns your code to this:

```
var color = Color.FromArgb(173, 216, 230).ToWdColor();
```

Comment: This actually sounds really good. So far I only had one line like that, but as soon as hit the next one, this is what I will do. As to "I cringe whenever I see the Microsoft.VisualBasic imported anywhere" -- my point exactly, that's why I never bothered to try that way.

Answer (score 1):

To set the color from RGB decimal :

```
Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = (Word.WdColor)(173 + 216 * 256 + 230 * 65536);
```

And from RGB hexadecimal:

```
Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = (Word.WdColor)0x00E6D8AD;
```